# create a dict of dict from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

i am trying to convert a data-frame to a dict in the below format:

```
df
    name   age country state  pincode
0  user1  10.0      in    tn      1.0
1  user2  11.0      us    tx      2.0
2  user3  12.0      eu    fr      3.0
```

```
{
   'user1':{'age':10,'country':'in','state':'tn','pincode':1},
   'user2':{'age':11,'country':'us','state':'tx','pincode':2},
   'user3':{'age':12,'country':'eu','state':'fr','pincode':3}
}
```

I am currently doing this by below statement:

```
op = {}
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    op[row['name']] = {'age':row['age'],'country':row['country'],'state':row['state'],'pincode':row['pincode']}
```

I want a the solution to work if there are additional columns added to the df. for example telephone number. Since the statement I have written is static it won't give me the additional rows in my output.
Is there a built in method in pandas that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient='index'`:

```
d = df.set_index('name').to_dict(orient='index')
print (d)
{'user1': {'age': 10.0, 'country': 'in', 'state': 'tn', 'pincode': 1.0}, 
 'user2': {'age': 11.0, 'country': 'us', 'state': 'tx', 'pincode': 2.0}, 
 'user3': {'age': 12.0, 'country': 'eu', 'state': 'fr', 'pincode': 3.0}}
```

If possible another columns which should be omited is possible crop them before or selecting:

```
d = df.set_index('name')[['age','country','state','pincode']].to_dict(orient='index')
```

Comment: One additional question. Suppose few columns don't have values. Is there a shortcut to remove them? Right now they have 'nan' as value

Comment: this works - {k1:{k:v for k,v in v1.items() if pd.notnull(v)} for k1, v1 in d.items()}. but any other in place solution?

Comment: @rakesh unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set `name` as index first:

```
df.set_index('name').to_dict('index')
```

Output:

```
{'user1': {'age': 10.0, 'country': 'in', 'state': 'tn', 'pincode': 1.0},
 'user2': {'age': 11.0, 'country': 'us', 'state': 'tx', 'pincode': 2.0},
 'user3': {'age': 12.0, 'country': 'eu', 'state': 'fr', 'pincode': 3.0}}
```

Comment: One additional question. Suppose if a few columns which don't have values. Is there a shortcut to remove them? Right now they have 'nan' as value
ex: {'age': 10.0, 'country': 'in', 'state': 'tn', 'pincode': 1.0,'ph':nan},
i would want the key ph to be removd

Answer (score 1):

This may not be very readable, but here's a one line dictionary comprehension:

```
{k:{a:b for a,b in zip(df.columns.tolist()[1:], v)}
 for k,v in zip(df['name'].to_list(), df.iloc[:,1:].to_numpy().tolist())}
```